# Passing Arguments To Custom Event Listener

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, callback

I have a JavaScript class called `EditorActivityBarItem`. To make the functionality more flexible, I decided to add a custom event listener that runs every time that element is clicked. I want to pass an argument `sideBar` to it so the user can modify the sideBar element as they want. But I am facing a few difficulties doing it.

Here's my code:

```js
class EditorActivityBarItem{
    constructor(name, icon, path, alert=[], callback=()=>{}){
        this._name = name;
        this._icon = icon;
        this._path = path;
        this._alert = alert;
        this._callback = callback();
    }

    get name(){
        return this._name;
    }
    get icon(){
        return this._icon;
    }
    get alert(){
        return this._alert;
    }
    get callback(){
        return this._callback;
    }
    getItem(affector){
        var element = $('<div class="activity-bar-item"></div>');
        var icon = $('<object class="activity-bar-item-icon" type="image/svg+xml" data="'+this._path+"/"+this._icon+'"></object>');
        icon.css("filter", "invert(1)")
        element.append(icon);
        tippy(element[0], {
            content: this.name,
            arrow: false,
            allowHTML: true,
            placement: 'right', 
            delay: [0, 0],
        })
        element.click(affector, this.callback)
        return element;
    }

    set name(value){
        this._name = value;
    }
    set icon(value){
        this._icon = value;
    }
    set alert(value){
        this._alert = value;
    }

    toggleSelection(){
        $('.activity-bar-item').toggleClass('selected')
    }
}
```

Then, I try to actually pass that `sideBar` element to the listener in a different method of a different class

Here is the code:

```js
create() {
  var window = $('<div class="editor-window"></div>');
  var titleBar = $('<div class="editor-title-bar"></div>');
  var applicationIcon = $('<div class="editor-application-icon"></div>');
  var applicationTitle = $('<div class="editor-application-title"></div>');
  var WindowsActionButtons = $('<div class="editor-action-buttons-windows"></div>');
  var windowsCloseButton = $('<div class="editor-close-button-windows"></div>');
  var windowsMaximizeButton = $('<div class="editor-maximize-button-windows"></div>');
  var windowsMinimizeButton = $('<div class="editor-minimize-button-windows"></div>');
  var macActionButtons = $('<div class="editor-action-buttons-mac"></div>');
  var macCloseButton = $('<div class="editor-close-button-mac"></div>');
  var macMaximizeButton = $('<div class="editor-maximize-button-mac"></div>');
  var macMinimizeButton = $('<div class="editor-minimize-button-mac"></div>');
  var menuBar = $('<div class="editor-menu-bar"></div>');
  var workspace = $('<div class="editor-workspace"></div>');
  var activityBar = $('<div class="editor-activity-bar"></div>');
  var activityBarTop = $('<div class="editor-activity-bar-top"></div>');
  var activityBarBottom = $('<div class="editor-activity-bar-bottom"></div>');
  var sideBar = $('<div class="editor-side-bar"></div>');
  var treeViewContainer = $('<div class="editor-tree-view-container"></div>');
  var editorGroups = $('<div class="editor-groups"></div>');
  var consoleContainer = $('<div class="editor-console-container"></div>');
  var consoleMenuBar = $('<div class="editor-console-container-menu-bar"></div>');
  var consoleSideBar = $('<div class="editor-console-container-side-bar"></div>');
  var statusBar = $('<div class="editor-status-bar"></div>');
  var statusBarLeft = $('<div class="editor-status-bar-left"></div>');
  var statusBarRight = $('<div class="editor-status-bar-right"></div>');

  let container = this.element;
  let options = this.options;

  container.append(window);
  window.append(titleBar);
  if (options.os === 'windows') {
    titleBar.append(applicationIcon);
    titleBar.append(applicationTitle);
    titleBar.append(WindowsActionButtons);
    WindowsActionButtons.append(windowsCloseButton);
    WindowsActionButtons.append(windowsMaximizeButton);
    WindowsActionButtons.append(windowsMinimizeButton);
  } else if (options.os === 'mac') {
    titleBar.append(macActionButtons);
    macActionButtons.append(macCloseButton);
    macActionButtons.append(macMaximizeButton);
    macActionButtons.append(macMinimizeButton);
    titleBar.append(applicationTitle);
  }
  window.append(menuBar);

  if (this.options.menuBar === 'custom') {
    for (const item in this.options.customMenuBarItems) {
      menuBar.append(this.options.customMenuBarItems[item].getItem());
    }
  } else if (this.options.menuBar === 'extend') {
    menuBar.append(new EditorWindowMenuBarItem('File').getItem());
    menuBar.append(new EditorWindowMenuBarItem('Edit').getItem());
    menuBar.append(new EditorWindowMenuBarItem('Selection').getItem());
    menuBar.append(new EditorWindowMenuBarItem('View').getItem());
    menuBar.append(new EditorWindowMenuBarItem('Go').getItem());
    menuBar.append(new EditorWindowMenuBarItem('Run').getItem());
    menuBar.append(new EditorWindowMenuBarItem('Terminal').getItem());
    menuBar.append(new EditorWindowMenuBarItem('Help').getItem());
    for (const item in this.options.customMenuBarItems) {
      menuBar.append(this.options.customMenuBarItems[item].getItem());
    }
  } else if (this.options.menuBar === 'default') {
    menuBar.append(new EditorWindowMenuBarItem('File').getItem());
    menuBar.append(new EditorWindowMenuBarItem('Edit').getItem());
    menuBar.append(new EditorWindowMenuBarItem('Selection').getItem());
    menuBar.append(new EditorWindowMenuBarItem('View').getItem());
    menuBar.append(new EditorWindowMenuBarItem('Go').getItem());
    menuBar.append(new EditorWindowMenuBarItem('Run').getItem());
    menuBar.append(new EditorWindowMenuBarItem('Terminal').getItem());
    menuBar.append(new EditorWindowMenuBarItem('Help').getItem());
  } else if (this.options.menuBar == 'none') {
    menuBar.hide();
  }

  window.append(workspace);
  workspace.append(activityBar);
  activityBar.append(activityBarTop);
  if (options.activityBarTop === 'default') {
    for (const item in defaults.activityBarTopItems) {
      activityBarTop.append(defaults.activityBarTopItems[item].getItem(sideBar));
      if (item == 0) {
        var sidebar = sideBar
        var first = defaults.activityBarTopItems[item]
        first.toggleSelection()
        first.callback = (sidebar) => {
          var title = $("<div class='editor-side-bar-title'>Explorer</div>")
          var widgets = $("<div class='editor-side-bar-widgets'><object class='activity-bar-item-icon' type='image/svg+xml' data='assets/icons/ellipsis'></object></div>")
          var container = $("<div class='file-explorer-container'></div>")
          for (const file in this.options.files) {
            var filetype = this.options.files[file].language
            var fileItem = $("<div class='file-explorer-item'><object class='lang-logo' type='image/svg+xml' data='assets/icons/files" + filetype + "'></object><div class='file-explorer-item-title'>" + this.options.files[file].name + "</div></div>")
            container.append(fileItem)
          }
          sidebar.append(title)
          sidebar.append(widgets)
          sidebar.append(container)
          alert("It works!")
          console.log(sidebar)
        }
        first.getItem().click()
      }
    }
  } else if (options.activityBarTop === 'custom') {
    for (const item in options.customActivityBarTopItems) {
      activityBarTop.append(options.customActivityBarTopItems[item].getItem());
      if (item == 0) {
        options.customActivityBarTopItems[item].toggleSelection()
      }
    }
  } else if (options.activityBarTop === 'extend') {
    for (const item in defaults.activityBarTopItems) {
      activityBarTop.append(defaults.activityBarTopItems[item].getItem());
      if (item == 0) {
        defaults.activityBarTopItems[item].toggleSelection()
      }
    }
    for (const item in options.customActivityBarTopItems) {
      activityBarTop.append(options.customActivityBarTopItems[item].getItem());
    }
  } else if (options.activityBarTop === 'none') {
    activityBarTop.hide();
  }

  activityBar.append(activityBarBottom);
  if (options.activityBarBottom === 'default') {
    for (const item in defaults.activityBarBottomItems) {
      activityBarBottom.append(defaults.activityBarBottomItems[item].getItem());
    }
  } else if (options.activityBarBottom === 'custom') {
    for (const item in options.customActivityBarBottomItems) {
      activityBarBottom.append(options.customActivityBarBottomItems[item].getItem());
    }
  } else if (options.activityBarBottom === 'extend') {
    for (const item in defaults.activityBarBottomItems) {
      activityBarBottom.append(defaults.activityBarBottomItems[item].getItem());
    }
    for (const item in options.customActivityBarBottomItems) {
      activityBarBottom.append(options.customActivityBarBottomItems[item].getItem());
    }
  } else if (options.activityBarBottom === 'none') {
    activityBarBottom.hide();
  }

  workspace.append(sideBar);
  sideBar.append(treeViewContainer);
}
```

Error on snippet line 89
Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Edit: Here is the error I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: sideBar.append is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.first.callback (editor.js:292:33)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:43064)
    at HTMLDivElement.v.handle (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:41048)
    at Object.trigger (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:71515)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:72110)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:3003)
    at S.fn.init.each (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:1481)
    at S.fn.init.trigger (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:72086)
    at S.fn.init.S.fn.<computed> [as click] (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:88570)
    at EditorWindow.create (editor.js:298:37)
```

Comment: You have two different spellings .....  sidebar vs sideBar

Comment: I added that to try and fix that error but it did not work

Comment: Couldn't possibly have the same error. Just saying *"did not work"* with no other debugging details is almost useless